# Synchronously returning the result of an AWS SDK promise?

Tags: php, aws-sdk

I'm using the AWS SDK and have a promise:

```
public function foo(){
    ...
    $pool = new CommandPool($client, $commands, [
        ....
    ]);
    $promise = $pool->promise();
    $result = $promise->wait();
    $promise->then(function () {
          return 'ok';
    });
}
```

How can I return the result of the promise synchronously from `foo`?

I've tried:

```
return $promise->then(function () {
       return 'ok';
 });
```

But this returns the promise itself, not `'ok'`, and causes an error in my framework:

```
The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "object" given.
```

Comment: I've edited your question to be more to the point and technically accurate, it's an interesting question now.

Comment: You're not assigning anything to the promise? Or if you are could you post that code...because right now it looks like you're trying to resolve null/undefined

Comment: Alex - have updated question.

Comment: $response = $promise->then(function () { return 'ok'; });
var_dump($response) please check what is result.

Comment: Suman Singh - object(GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise)#598 (6) { ["state":"GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise":private]=> string(7) "pending" ["result":"GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise":private]=> NULL.....

Comment: Dude… you've already used `wait()` in your code; just in the wrong order…

Comment: I'm fairly sure that the result of $promise->wait() can't be assigned to $result, try chaining it onto the end of $promise->then(functiion(){})->wait()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AWS SDK uses guzzle/promises, and they can be synchronously resolved using the `wait` method:

```
return $promise->then(function () { return 'ok'; })->wait();
```

See https://github.com/guzzle/promises#synchronous-wait and http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/guide/promises.html.

Comment: I don't know, does it? Where did you find that example?

Comment: So another quick question, this will wait for all of my promises to complete, then perform the then function, then return the result 'ok'?

Comment: `then` returns a new promise, which resolves when the previous promise it derived from resolves. So, first `$promise` will resolve, then your callback is called which returns a new promise, then its value is returned by `wait`. And `wait` ensures that the surrounding `foo` function pauses until this entire chain has resolved.